# Deja-dup keeps asking for password

Tags: 16.04, backup, deja-dup, duplicity

I have a problem with `deja-dup`. When I try to make a backup to a server of mine it start the backup for +- 10 seconds and then asks for my encryption password over and over again.

What I did so far:

- `delete ~/.cache/deja-dup/`
- delete the directory to which I upload on my server and created a new one

And I tried to debug the issue:

```
export DEJA_DUP_DEBUG=1
deja-dup --backup
```

Deja-dup starts scanning, then says it creating first backup after which de debug log states:

```
DUPLICITY: INFO 1
DUPLICITY: . GPG error detail: Traceback (most recent call last):
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1532, in <module>
DUPLICITY: .     with_tempdir(main)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1526, in with_tempdir
DUPLICITY: .     fn()
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1380, in main
DUPLICITY: .     do_backup(action)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1496, in do_backup
DUPLICITY: .     full_backup(col_stats)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 567, in full_backup
DUPLICITY: .     globals.backend)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 425, in write_multivol
DUPLICITY: .     at_end = gpg.GPGWriteFile(tarblock_iter, tdp.name, globals.gpg_profile, globals.volsize)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/gpg.py", line 356, in GPGWriteFile
DUPLICITY: .     file.close()
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/gpg.py", line 241, in close
DUPLICITY: .     self.gpg_failed()
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/gpg.py", line 226, in gpg_failed
DUPLICITY: .     raise GPGError(msg)
DUPLICITY: . GPGError: GPG Failed, see log below:
DUPLICITY: . ===== Begin GnuPG log =====
DUPLICITY: . gpg: keyblock resource `/etc/pacman.d/gnupg/pubring.gpg': file open error
DUPLICITY: . ===== End GnuPG log =====
DUPLICITY: . 
DUPLICITY: . 

DUPLICITY: ERROR 31 GPGError
DUPLICITY: . GPGError: GPG Failed, see log below:
DUPLICITY: . ===== Begin GnuPG log =====
DUPLICITY: . gpg: keyblock resource `/etc/pacman.d/gnupg/pubring.gpg': file open error
DUPLICITY: . ===== End GnuPG log =====
DUPLICITY: .
```

As far as I know it makes sense that duplicity can't open `/etc/pacman.d/gnupg/pubring.gpg` since I'm not running arch.

Anyone any suggestions as to why duplicity `/` deja-dup tries to open `/etc/pacman.d/` instead of using my default gpg keyring?

Comment: You should file a bug report  (see http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug )

Comment: Yeah, I didn't do that since I am on a recent (two weeks old) installation of Ubuntu and google-ing didn't come up with other people encountering the same issue so I hope someone can help me with fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

Just fixed the issue, for some reason there was a line in my ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf "keyring /etc/pacman.d/gnupg/pubring.gpg"

Which I commented out and now it works.