# Ubuntu 16.04.02 | Deja-dup 34.2 | Restore keep asking "Encryption Password Needed"

Tags: encryption, restore, deja-dup

Please help..!

I already file a bug report in Launchpad. But I'm desperate to seek help, so I ask again here.

FYI. I never put password on my backed up files.

I made debug report as suggested here [Deja-dup keeps asking for password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802449/deja-dup-keeps-asking-for-password). And below is the debug report

--- Begin Debug Report ---

DUPLICITY: DEBUG 1
DUPLICITY: . File duplicity-full.20160806T050831Z.vol169.difftar.gpg is part of known set

--snipped--

DUPLICITY: DEBUG 1
DUPLICITY: . Ignoring file (rejected by backup set) 'duplicity-full-signatures.20151219T084715Z.sigtar.gpg'

---continue the same as ---

DUPLICITY: DEBUG 1
DUPLICITY: . File duplicity-full.20170304T005339Z.vol796.difftar.gpg is part of known set

DUPLICITY: DEBUG 1
DUPLICITY: . Found backup chain [Sat Dec 19 15:47:15 2015]-[Sat Dec 19 15:47:15 2015]

DUPLICITY: DEBUG 1
DUPLICITY: . Found backup chain [Sat Aug  6 12:08:31 2016]-[Sat Aug  6 12:08:31 2016]

DUPLICITY: DEBUG 1
DUPLICITY: . Found backup chain [Sat Mar  4 07:53:39 2017]-[Sat Mar  4 07:53:39 2017]

DUPLICITY: NOTICE 1
DUPLICITY: . Last full backup date: Sat Mar  4 07:53:39 2017

DUPLICITY: INFO 3

DUPLICITY: backend BackendWrapper

DUPLICITY: archive-dir (() /home/enriko/.cache/deja-dup/a23b52e7600e5d6476356464c6391399 dir)

DUPLICITY: chain-no-sig 0

DUPLICITY:  full 20150811T142405Z 516 enc

DUPLICITY: chain-no-sig 1

DUPLICITY:  full 20151219T084715Z 411 enc

DUPLICITY: chain-no-sig 2

DUPLICITY:  full 20160806T050831Z 673 enc

DUPLICITY: chain-complete

DUPLICITY:  full 20170304T005339Z 1043 enc

DUPLICITY: orphaned-sets-num 0

DUPLICITY: incomplete-sets-num 0

DUPLICITY: . Collection Status

DUPLICITY: . -----------------

DUPLICITY: . Connecting with backend: BackendWrapper

DUPLICITY: . Archive dir: /home/enriko/.cache/deja-dup/a23b52e7600e5d6476356464c6391399

DUPLICITY: .

DUPLICITY: . Found 3 secondary backup chains.

DUPLICITY: . Secondary chain 1 of 3:

DUPLICITY: . -------------------------

DUPLICITY: . Chain start time: Tue Aug 11 21:24:05 2015

DUPLICITY: . Chain end time: Tue Aug 11 21:24:05 2015

DUPLICITY: . Number of contained backup sets: 1

DUPLICITY: . Total number of contained volumes: 516

DUPLICITY: .  Type of backup set:                            Time:      Num volumes:

DUPLICITY: .                 Full         Tue Aug 11 21:24:05 2015               516

DUPLICITY: . -------------------------

DUPLICITY: .

DUPLICITY: . Secondary chain 2 of 3:

DUPLICITY: . -------------------------

DUPLICITY: . Chain start time: Sat Dec 19 15:47:15 2015

DUPLICITY: . Chain end time: Sat Dec 19 15:47:15 2015

DUPLICITY: . Number of contained backup sets: 1

DUPLICITY: . Total number of contained volumes: 411

DUPLICITY: .  Type of backup set:                            Time:      Num volumes:

DUPLICITY: .                 Full         Sat Dec 19 15:47:15 2015               411

DUPLICITY: . -------------------------

DUPLICITY: .

DUPLICITY: . Secondary chain 3 of 3:

DUPLICITY: . -------------------------

DUPLICITY: . Chain start time: Sat Aug  6 12:08:31 2016

DUPLICITY: . Chain end time: Sat Aug  6 12:08:31 2016

DUPLICITY: . Number of contained backup sets: 1

DUPLICITY: . Total number of contained volumes: 673

DUPLICITY: .  Type of backup set:                            Time:      Num volumes:

DUPLICITY: .                 Full         Sat Aug  6 12:08:31 2016               673

DUPLICITY: . -------------------------

DUPLICITY: .

DUPLICITY: .

DUPLICITY: . Found primary backup chain with matching signature chain:

DUPLICITY: . -------------------------

DUPLICITY: . Chain start time: Sat Mar  4 07:53:39 2017

DUPLICITY: . Chain end time: Sat Mar  4 07:53:39 2017

DUPLICITY: . Number of contained backup sets: 1

DUPLICITY: . Total number of contained volumes: 1043

DUPLICITY: .  Type of backup set:                            Time:      Num volumes:

DUPLICITY: .                 Full         Sat Mar  4 07:53:39 2017              1043

DUPLICITY: . -------------------------

DUPLICITY: . No orphaned or incomplete backup sets found.

DUPLICITY: INFO 1

DUPLICITY: . PASSPHRASE variable not set, asking user.

DUPLICITY: DEBUG 1

DUPLICITY: . Releasing lockfile /home/enriko/.cache/deja-dup/a23b52e7600e5d6476356464c6391399/lockfile.lock

DUPLICITY: DEBUG 1

DUPLICITY: . Removing still remembered temporary file /tmp/duplicity-RCCpAU-tempdir/mkstemp-7KNhAG-1

DUPLICITY: ERROR 30 EOFError

DUPLICITY: . Traceback (most recent call last):

DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1532, in

DUPLICITY: .     with_tempdir(main)

DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1526, in with_tempdir

DUPLICITY: .     fn()

DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1380, in main

DUPLICITY: .     do_backup(action)

DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1454, in do_backup

DUPLICITY: .     globals.gpg_profile.passphrase = get_passphrase(1, action)

DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 198, in get_passphrase

DUPLICITY: .     pass1 = getpass_safe(_("GnuPG passphrase for decryption:") + " ")

DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 93, in getpass_safe

DUPLICITY: .     return getpass.getpass(message)

DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/getpass.py", line 83, in unix_getpass

DUPLICITY: .     passwd = fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)

DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/getpass.py", line 118, in fallback_getpass

DUPLICITY: .     return _raw_input(prompt, stream)

DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/getpass.py", line 135, in _raw_input

DUPLICITY: .     raise EOFError

DUPLICITY: . EOFError

DUPLICITY: .

--- End Debug Report ---

Please help. And thank you for your support.

Comment: Oh My God...!!!

Now I accidentally lost all my backups. Kindly forget this question.

Oh My GOD!!!